# BufferedReader String is not working with if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, bufferedreader

Code:

```java
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    String[] args = line.split(" ");
    try {
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("x")){
            System.out.println("ssssss");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, everything works fine, the String being received is the one I expected to be received but, when it reaches the if statement it seems to return false // not work, no exceptions are thrown and this should work.

Output:

```
x x x
```

Expected Output:

```
x x x
ssssss
```

How I am sending the string:

```java
public static boolean send(OutputStream outputStream, String string){
    try{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
        writer.write(string + "\n");
        writer.flush();
    }catch (IOException e){

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you passing as input?

Comment: @Jason the input I am sending through the send method is `x x x`

Comment: Can you show the actual method that the reader is called in? Can you also show an example of using send function and ur presumed read function? Thank you.